# Restrict the use of a Clojure fn

Tags: security, api, clojure

I have an application where Clojure code is evaluated either **from the application classpath** or as a **remote file store resource**.

Only the administrator has access to the classpath location, but all users can provide their code on the remote store.  In order to facilitate some operations, the application API includes a `auth/as-admin` macro that executes the input forms if they were executed as a logged in administrator, but obviously I don't want it to be successfully used in user provided code.

How can I reliably restrict the use of `auth/as-admin` to classpath-only code, preventing any "malicious" `binding` in user code trying to circumvent the constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the code and before evaluating it, you can iterate it and remove dangerous calls,

```
(ns tmp
  (:require [clojure.zip :as zip])
  (:use clojure.contrib.pprint))

;;stolen from http://nakkaya.com/2011/06/29/ferret-an-experimental-clojure-compiler/
(defn remove-form [tree pred]
  (loop [loc (zip/seq-zip tree)]
    (if (zip/end? loc)
      (zip/root loc)
      (recur
       (zip/next
        (if (pred (zip/node loc))
          (zip/remove loc)
          loc))))))


(remove-form (read-string (str \( "(+ 1 1)
                                  (println \"No print\")"
                               \)))
             #(and (seq? %)
                   (= 'println (first %))))
```

this will remove all println calls,

```
tmp=> ((+ 1 1))
```

or you can use a library such as clj-sandbox that is designed for this.

Comment: Sandboxing using policies puts restrictions on the whole JVM, right? I still need to grant access to `auth/as-admin` to trusted system code, I don't know if I really can go that way. I'll give a shot to your suggestion.

Comment: I do not know how you read or receive the code to be executed but you just need to run untrusted code through the filter this does not effect any thing on the JVM, just the sexpressions you pass to it.

Comment: Yep, I got it, I was just commenting the `clj-sandbox` suggestion, as it does require the use of JVM wide settings (policies file)

Answer (score 1):

hiredman maintains the clojurebot on the clojure IRC channel. this bot is a great example of how to sandbox clojure code from untrusted sources.

https://github.com/hiredman/clojurebot

Thanks Hiredman! Clojurebot it awesome :)